# How to get iWork and iLife after upgrading to Yosemite from Mavericks?

Tags: macos, iwork, ilife

I bought a mid-2014 MBP Retina (activated on 30/09/2014) from a friend and did a re-installation of Mavericks, then upgraded to Yosemite right after the re-installation (without associating the mac to my Apple account. I only did that after upgrading to Yosemite.)

Now I realise that I cannot get the iWork and iLife apps for free (I should have associated the mac to my Apple account and use it to get iWork and iLife before upgrading, right?).

Is there anyway to get that apps without re-install everything ?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: afaik, it takes 90 days for the old association to finally drop. Aside from that, the licenses for Apple software do not transfer with the machine, you must re-purchase. You should in fact, for many reasons, completely wipe the machine & start from scratch.

Comment: @Tetsujin: The machine was activated on 30/9/14 so maybe I can negotiate with the Genius Bar to have those apps :P
I can actually do a recovery via internet to re-install Mavericks but it's a pain to re-install everything after that :(

Comment: This might help - http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/80337/do-all-macs-come-with-ilife-apps It does seem that it's a 'race' to who gets to register the free versions, but the last answer gives more hope

Comment: @Tetsujin: thanks, that was useful. I thought that a re-installation would let me get those apps for free, but according to the answers to that question, it depends on whether the previous owner had already got them.

Comment: Yes - it appears that the 'machine' itself is eligible for one install of each, the race is who uses up that install first. Odd way to do it, but it does appear that with a little persuasion, they may allow you to bypass that. Wish you luck :)

Answer (score 1):

It is not about iCloud account but about Mac Apps store logged in account and upgrading said apps under it.

If you have iLife and iWork trials installed under Mavericks you will get them associated to your Apple ID logged into App Store. Can't say for sure but maybe you have to update them for this. Don't have to download them all the way though when they started updating.

And no there is no way to do it except having Mavericks. You might use another Mac with Mavericks for this (provided it doesn't have iLife and iWork already installed of course) or you might install Mavericks on your Mac — you can create a temporal partition for this, you can use external drive, USB or even SD card for this too.

Comment: Thanks. Actually by "iCloud account" I meant "Apple account".
Marvericks is no longer available on the Mac App Store while I haven't never purchased it because it was pre-installed on my Mac. 
I can do a recovery via internet to re-install Mavericks but it's a pain to re-install everything after that :( 
Maybe I should go to an Apple Store asking the Genius Bar whether they can give me those apps :/

Comment: Choose your poison. But since you are not original buyer of that MBP you might have hard time getting that apps through genius. Anyway please keep us posted.